# Bash: How can I insert a line to a specific location within a file?

Tags: linux, apache, bash

I'm automating the process of creating virtual hosts in my company and I'd like to add this line: `ServerAlias sitename.booking.local` into a file called sitename.com.conf which looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.sitename.com
   ServerAlias sitename.com
   ServerAlias sitename.booking.local
   DocumentRoot /site/http/travel/itn
   CustomLog logs/access_sitename_log combined
   DirectoryIndex default.php index.php index.html index.phtml index.cgi index.htm
   ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/
   <Directory /site/http/travel/itn >
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want that line to be within the `<virtualhost></virtualhost>` and add it under the last `ServerAlias` line in the file, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Any specific reason to add it under the last `ServerAlias` line only?

Comment: No, it's not a must, but it has to be within the `<virtualhost></virtualhost>` and not within the `<directory></directory>`.

Comment: Server alias allows multiple values on same line.. does not need a new line... _sed "s/ServerAlias.*/& newvalue/" -i vhostfile_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk  -v a="mysite" '/<VirtualHost /{v=1}
     v && /^ *ServerAlias/{{$0="   ServerAlias " a ".booking.local" RS $0; v=0} 
     /<\/VirtualHost>/{v=0} 1' file
```

**OURPUT:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.sitename.com
   ServerAlias sitename.booking.local
   ServerAlias sitename.com
   DocumentRoot /site/http/travel/itn
   CustomLog logs/access_sitename_log combined
   DirectoryIndex default.php index.php index.html index.phtml index.cgi index.htm
   ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/
   <Directory /site/http/travel/itn >
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the sitename.booking.local is actually built from $site and .booking.local , so how would the line look if the site is a variable?
Will this work?
`awk '/<VirtualHost /{v=1} v && /^ *ServerAlias/{$0="   ServerAlias $site.booking.local" RS $0; v=0} /<\/VirtualHost>/{v=0} 1' file`

Comment: see update on how to pass dynamic sitename into variable `a` above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we want to insert a line into a certain place in the document, then you can use sed like this to add to the 4th line:

```
sed '4a\     ServerAlias sitename.booking.local' myfile.xml > myfile.xml
```

This is obviously dangerous, if the file structure can change in the future or so, let us just add this line right after ServerName , so it will be like

```
sed -i 's/ServerName www.sitename.com/ServerName www.sitename.com\\n   ServerAlias sitename.booking.local/g' myfile.xml
```